# Select into from one sql server into another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select data from one table (T1, in DB1) in one server (Data.Old.S1) into data in another table (T2, in DB2) in another server (Data.Latest.S2). How can I do this ?

Please note the way the servers are named. The query should take care of that too. That is, 
SQL server should not be confused about fully qualified table names. For example - this could confuse SQL server - Data.Old.S1.DB1.dbo.T1.

I also want "mapping" . Eg Col1 of T1 should go to Col18 of T2 etc.

Comment: How do you have DB1 and DB2 talking to each other?  Linked servers?  This can be accomplished a few ways...best choice will depend on how often you want to access the old server (1 time migrate, or constantly going update).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx).  then use an [openquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) sql statement.

Comment: what about selecting Col1 of T1 into Col17 of T2 where {some condition}

Comment: The linked server worked great.  For the actual sql query, I did not use openquery, I just wrote a standard insert query, but fully qualified the linked server table using syntax from another answer below like the following: [linked_server].[databasename].dbo.[tablename]

Answer (score 9):

Use Sql Server Management Studio's Import feature.

1. right click on database in the object explorer and select import
2. select your source database
3. select your target database
4. choose the option to 'specify custom query' and just select your data from T1, in DB1
5. choose your destination table in the destination database i.e. T2
6. execute the import

Answer (score 6):

```
select * into [newtable] from [linked_server].[databasename].dbo.[tablename]
```

Comment: what about selecting Col1 of T1 into Col17 of T2 where {some condition}

Comment: This is not generally true.

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz - what is not generally true

Comment: You should use fully qualified table names.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer.
Make sure the source server (server1) is linked to the destination server (server2):

```
SELECT * 
INTO Server2.DB2.dbo.T2
FROM OPENQUERY (server1
                , ' SELECT col_one, col_two, ...
                    FROM DB1.dbo.T1 
                    WHERE ...
                    ...
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one time linked server in appropriate.
But if it neede to move data frequently ,replication is better and easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating it by insisting on SQL.  In SSMS, right-click the server you want to export from, select "Tasks", "Export", and let the wizard walk you through the steps of selecting your target server and table, which includes mapping all of the columns exactly as you're trying to do with your SQL situation.  All the functionality you seem to be looking for is already there.

There's no need for linked servers, SSIS, or anything else to accomplish this.  It's already built into SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score -1):

You could look into this:

[Clicky!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190923.aspx)

Or you could use SSIS, which would probably be much simpler.

Comment: I want SQL. I do have SSIS, but i need to do it by sql as per my situation

Comment: what about selecting Col1 of T1 into Col17 of T2 where {some condition}