# Get the script of the results of a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to get information from a table, but not all columns, I need to create a new table based on the information obtained in the query. The other table is on a different server, so I need the script

Comment: Make your question clear. its a little bit confusing to understand..

Comment: I need to convert Select results into Insert script

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: are the servers on the same network? you can link the servers then do a simple Insert INTO .. Select. If not on same server, you can use SSIS to transfer just certain columns of a table to another server/database.

Comment: check this out [SELECT INTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459594/select-into-from-one-sql-server-into-another)

Comment: The servers are on different networks

Comment: @Richard you can use the bcp utility to dump out the contents of a table, and the same utility to reconstruct the table on the other side. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/

Comment: another option is to you the built in data scripter in SSMS. See the answer with the most upvotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312576/how-to-simply-generate-the-create-sql-script-for-a-table-and-data